# Modify Damerau–Levenshtein distance to allow reversals of longer substrings

Tags: strings, string-metrics

Is there a way to modify the Damerau–Levenshtein distance algorithm to allow the transposition of substrings? By this I mean that instead of simply turning "ba" to "ab" you could calculate "worra" to "arrow" and have that cost only be 1. An example might help:

If you had a target of timeflieslikeanarrow and a staring string of tfemiliilzejeworrbna, you would have the following operations for a minimum of 6. (step 1 being the start and step 7 being the end, 6 actual operations).

1. tfemiliilzejeworrbna (the target)
2. tfemiliilzejeanbrrow (transpose)
3. tfemiliezlijeanbrrow (transpose)
4. timefliezlijeanbrrow (transpose)
5. timefliezlijeanarrow (a substitution)
6. timefliezlikeanarrow (a substitution)
7. timeflieslikeanarrow (a substitution)

Comment: Have you tried modifying the usual dynamic programming algorithm?

Comment: That's what I am attempting to do but I'm sort of at a loss in terms of checking for that "multiple transpose" (the arrow example from above).

Comment: If you limit the length of the substrings being transposed and you do NOT have any overlapping transpose then this is just one more case in addition to the 3 in original Levenshtein.

Comment: If you allow reversals of unlimited length of reversals, I think the DP algorithm still works in principle but you'll get another linear factor. Overlapping reversals kill the "optimality criterion" and DP would no longer be possible.